# Node JS PCRE regex and transforms support

Tags: regex, node.js, npm, pcre, npm-install

I've a need to apply a lot of PCRE regexes with multiple backreferences and apply perl style transforms `s/\/\/(\d+)/$1/s` in a Node JS app.

I searched around and found these two libraries for this purpose:

https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre (Regex application)

https://github.com/tokuhirom/node-perl (Perl style transforms)

I'm getting a lot of NPM errors during installation of these modules in Node v5.9.0.

The node-pcre library has an [issue](https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre/issues/13) which says the library stops working after NodeJS 0.10 version due to change in V8 API

I ran into installation issues for node-perl library as well.

Is there a way for me to get support for PCRE regexes and transforms in Node v5.9.0

Thanks

EDIT: One of the comments below was to specify a PCRE regex that am trying which does not work in javascript. Here's the example:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var regex = '<input type=\"hidden\"\s*name=\"itemId\"\s*value=\"(?P<sku>[\w\-]+)\"[^<]*>.*?<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\'JavaScript\'[^<]*>.*?(\g{sku}Matrix\s*\=.*?<\/SCRIPT>)';
var page = fs.readFileSync("./page.html");

var re = new RegExp(regex);
var matchStr = "";

matchStr = page.replace(re, function (match, $1) { return $1; });
console.log(matchStr);
```

**Response**

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /<input type="hidden"s*name="itemId"s*value="(?P<sku>[w-]+)"[^<]*>.*?<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'[^<]*>.*?(g{sku}Matrixs*=.*?</SCRIPT>)/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/project/abc.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3
```

Comment: for what reason Javascript regexes don't suffice?

Comment: The regexes have all been written in PCRE before. I've a need where I need to use them in my app

Comment: Except if these regexes use special PCRE features, most of them should work directly with the Javascript regex engine, and the others with few changes.

Comment: @alpha_cod: Could you share the regexps?

Comment: Sample regex:

<input type=\"hidden\"\s*name=\"itemId\"\s*value=\"(?P<sku>[\w\-]+)\"[^<]*>.*?<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\'JavaScript\'[^<]*>.*?(\g{sku}Matrix\s*\=.*?<\/SCRIPT>)

using this PCRE feature:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: I need PCRE for NodeJS, but [the project seems abandoned](https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre/issues/15)... Must  use another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with

```
sudo npm install perl
sudo npm install pcre
```

for me. Probably binding/linking with sys libs required sudo/root permissions.
The above commands did the trick for me.

So if anyone else has a need to install these modules on the latest node managed via nvm, just install these modules using sudo and rest of the dependencies without sudo as usual.

Answer (score 1):

In the regex you gave, you are using named groups, which JS doesn't support. As a result, you'll need to use numbered groups, which pushes your desired capture to `$2`, in this case.

`<input type=\"hidden\"\s*name=\"itemId\"\s*value=\"([\w\-]+)\"[^<]*>.*?<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\'JavaScript\'[^<]*>.*?(\1Matrix\s*\=.*?<\/SCRIPT>)';`

It should work like this:

```
matchStr = page.replace(re, function (match, $2) { return $2; });
```

1. Find the group mentioned with your external `$#` statement. Remember which one it is.
2. You'll need to count the capture groups, both named (`(?P<NAME>)`) and unnamed `()`

   - `([abc])(?:[efg])(?P<NAME>[hij])` Remember, here `[abc]` is 1, and `[hij]` is 2 because `(?:)` is non capturing.
3. Then, find any references to the named captures (`\g<NAME>`) and replace with `\#`, where `#` is the number from the last step.
4. Change the `$#`s in your JS code after getting the new number for the group found in the first step.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I dont have control over the regexes. The regexes are fed from a database maintained by another team/system. Would it be possible to directly use these regexes in javascript.

Comment: @alpha_cod JS does not use PCRE, so it's not going to be that easy. You could use a library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcre-to-regexp), (although the online tester seems to be broken). It seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: I understand.. I wish to know if there's any way to get the above modules 
node-pcre and node-perl working with NodeJS v5.9.0. That would solve my usecase..